# HTML Image size

Tags: html

I am exporting my web images from PSD by 'Save For Web' option along with using its Quality and Format controls as per the standards but when I check my image size they are heavy than the expectation. I see the image sizes on other web. Their GIF images are too small. i.e a bullet arrow GIF image (12px X 48px) is near around 90 bytes but when I create the same image in PSD and export as GIF my size goes upto 1 KB. I just wanted to know that is their any other way to export or create images for web to gain lower size?

Answer (score 2):

You can check how many colors are you using.
If you create a GIF with less colors you get a smaller GIF.

The size also depends on how many colors are in the image, maybe the 90 bytes gif is pure black and white and yours have more colors.

Answer (score 1):

When you Save For Web in Photoshop, there are a few variables you can play to gain lower size, that you already use. I tried to explain some for other users who find this question,in case you already know how them works:

[image]

**Lossy:** Lossy compression lets you compress more bytes out. Higher value produces low image quality and less weight.

**Colors:** More number of colors used in the image causes higher size image, as aleixventa says in his answer.

**Web Snap:** That's the option to convert the color of the image to web safe colors. More web safe colors results in a smaller image.

**Combobox "No Dither":** Dithering mixes pixels of the gradients to simulate the missing colors. You could retrieve more specific info about this feature [here](http://www.underwaterphotography.com/photoshop/photoshop/help.html). BTW, less percentaje of difussion dittering results in higher image.

With all these variables in mind, you can see the total weight while playing with them:

[image]

Comment: @AmreshRaut If this solution works for you, could you accept it, to help other user who find same question? Thanks, and glad to help :)